# Error publishing a webservice in IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7

I get the following error message while trying to publish my webservice in Vista IIS 7.0:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.Compiler Error Message: CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\helloworld\a71cdc49\1d988805\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.cdcab7d2.mchc3ynk.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: solution :

Goto -> C:\Windows->right click Temp folder and select Properties and change the Security tab->Group Users select IIS_USERS and then give the Full Permission and give OK.

It will show one warning message and give OK . and Restart IIS7.0 and browse your published virtual directory application .ASMX . You can get the webservices listed page without problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try granting full access permissions to the ASP.NET account (Network Service) for the %TEMP% folder (c:\windows\temp).