# Compile time error: "Could not write to output file ... Access is denied"

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error at compile time:

> `CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7529765b\d6c35794\App_Web_uclogin.ascx.5a9fc98b.zqr8lwaw.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '`

Could anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Clear your c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ directory.

Answer (score 3):

Restart IIS, then delete everything in `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`.

Comment: but it is not solving my problem still i am getting the same error

Comment: @Vijay: Did you restart you VS?

Answer (score 0):

See [Error publishing a webservice in IIS 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041032/error-publishing-a-webservice-in-iis-7-0)

> Try granting full access permissions to the ASP.NET account (Network Service) for the %TEMP% folder (c:\windows\temp)

Although, I found adding full access permissions for IIS_IUSRS instead of Network Service to solve this problem for me